# Can COVID-19 be damaging lung without showing fever?

Tags: covid-19, virus, lungs, clinical-study, chest

Given that a man of 39 years without underlying health condition, is having chest discomfort and tightness, which is more discomfort during evening and night before fall asleep. He don't have cold and cough, nor have fever and he is  physically active.
My concern is that whether he is fighting with COVID-19 infection.
Can COVID-19 be damaging the lung without showing fever?
Thank you.

Comment: You need to reframe your question in a format that's acceptable as an educational question. Currently you're seeking personal advice

Comment: For related to the lungs, the answers [here](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/21681/why-recovered-patients-develop-lung-disease-due-covid-19)

Answer (score 2):

The range of symptoms for people infected with SARS-CoV-2 are extreme.  There are reports of asymptomatic children with CT scans showing viral pneumonia.

> Among the paediatric patients in our study, just under a third were asymptomatic. Moreover, a fifth had pneumonia only and needed radiographic examination to be identified.

With respect to the question of whether one can have ongoing pneumonic process without a fever, then yes, that is possible.

Case 5 in the link below presented only with a runny nose and sore throat.  Fever is not mentioned as it is in the other cases so one assumes she was not febrile.  But CT scan 3 days later showed ground-glass opacities.  Her throat swab was positive by PCR for SARS-CoV-2.

https://www.thelancet.com/journals/laninf/article/PIIS1473-3099(20)30198-5/fulltext

https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/all.14289

Comment: Wow, I was not aware of the reports of asymptomatic children with CT scans showing viral pneumonia, where did you see this?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Does this pediatric patients were healthy?